# With websphere liberty or apache tomcat 8 or in java code in general how to print the full path of third-party or first-party class

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I am trying to see where a first party class and third-party class are loaded from say a websphere liberty as well as apache tomcat.  When I use -verbose:class, I see a bunch of paths but don't see the path in question.  It looks like liberty related paths but not the third-party path was looking for.

For example, let's say the class is just org/apache/loggger/Logger.class where is that class?

I tried Reflections library, was sure if that was the right use case.

I tried these approaches below, didn't find what was looking for. The class is there at compile time.  Also couldn't find any third-party classes this way.

```
    final ClassLoader loader = ServletVers2.class.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println(loader.getResource("com/ca/services/servlet/ServletVers2.class"));
    System.out.println(loader.getResource("com/ca/apps/shared/utils/BuildVersion.class"));

    final ClassLoader classloader2 = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    final ClassLoader classloader3 = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent();

    System.out.println(loader.getResource("org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.class"));
    System.out.println(loader.getResource("org/apache/log4j/Logger.class"));

    System.out.println(classloader2.getResource("org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.class"));
    System.out.println(classloader2.getResource("org/apache/log4j/Logger.class"));

    System.out.println(classloader3.getResource("org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.class"));
    System.out.println(classloader3.getResource("org/apache/log4j/Logger.class"));
    
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.apps.shared.utils.BuildVersion", new SubTypesScanner(false));
```

Comment: Just use `Logger.class.getResource("Logger.class")`. Alternatively, `org.apache.log4j.Logger.class.getClassLoader().getResource( "org/apache/log4j/Logger.class")` would do (as that class shouldn’t be loaded by the bootstrap loader).

Comment: That is in all the code above, all return null.  It can't find the logger class.

I was actually trying to see at compile time it maybe available but not at runtime.

Comment: A call like `Logger.class.getResource("Logger.class")` is *not* in the code above. It would be the only call that uses the right class loader *and* prevents from misspelling the package. And if you can call a method on `Logger.class`, then obviously, the class *is* available at runtime. All your attempts above are either, making guesswork about the class loader or inconsistent regarding the path/package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, this should work.  It is not entirely what I was looking for but will continue with this.

Logger.class.getResource("Logger.class"). Alternatively, org.apache.log4j.Logger.class.getClassLoader().getResource( "org/apache/log4j/Logger.class")